# Add text to image without saving

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to apply some text over a banner image in C#. So far i have a class control that pulls through the title, href and image src but i want to add text to it without saving it.

So i want to use the title i pulled through and apply it ontop.

Below is graphics i have attempted to apply to it. I just want to overlay text on it, not create a new image as well.

```
private void GenerateBannerTitle()
{
    Bitmap bannerSource = new Bitmap(PhysicalBannerPath);
    //bannerSource.Save(PhysicalBannerPath);
    RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(430, 50, 650, 50);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bannerSource))
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        g.DrawString("hfsdfdsfds", new Font("courier sans", 100, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, rectf);
    }
}
```

Any help or ideas. Can this be done via inline css in c# or can there be a way to alter what i have now to just apply it ontop.

At the moment i am just pulling through the image. Its just applying text that i need to understand and get working.

Comment: take a look at MemoryStream for the image and for the return type take a look at File Stream Content

Comment: why don't you just apply simply a label?

Comment: @CiroCorvino how do i do that? can you help please

Comment: @DB I don't know if I really understand your issue, but as far as I understood you need to put some text over an image.. if this is your need, then you can add to your aspx a web control named Label (or similar) in every position you want respect your banner image and then put some text in its value filed or attribute. If you need further help you can add the aspx markupcode  (a little portion that comprehend the banner markup) in your question..

Comment: @CiroCorvino i dont need or want to add a label onto the page. im trying to make this reusable. So all i will need is to call the banner class control and then itll do it for you.

Comment: @DB ok, then for the sake of clearness you should specify your pre-requirements in the question and clarify exactly your real aims, mostly because yours it is a not so trivial question

Comment: @CiroCorvino apologies. but do you understand my issues?

Comment: @DB explain well what is your issue, putting yourself in the mind of whom that read your question without knowing anything of your assumptions

Comment: you could make the image the background image of a div, and then just have some text inside the div, positioned however you need. If you want it re-usable you can make it a user control (.ascx), and have some code which can set a different background image, or different text, or other CSS properties, whatever you need to make it configurable.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tristank/2008/11/06/dont-use-office-applications-or-gdi-or-system-drawing-or-wininet-in-a-server-application-or-asp-net/

Comment: While you shouldn't use GDI+ from IIS... if you are I would suggest having a httphandler/server request that returns the imagestream and just put the URL to that handler in the `src` for the `img` tag.  Stuffing the image in base64 as shown below increases the download size by around 60%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a memory stream to return the image as a base64 string

```
private string GenerateBannerTitle()
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(PhysicalBannerPath);
        RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(430, 50, 650, 50);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            using (var arialFont = new Font("Arial", 10))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
                g.DrawString("hfsdfdsfds", new Font("courier sans", 100, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, rectf);
            }
        }


        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        var arr = new byte[ms.Length];

        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(arr, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        ms.Close();

        var strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);

        return strBase64;

    }
```

And the show it in html like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,the returned data"/>
```